# Cumulative Distribution of X/Y

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X, Y be independent exponential variables with rates $\alpha$, and $\beta$.  Find the c.d.f. of X/Y.

So far, I let Z = X/Y.
I can then show $f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x|f_{X,Y}(x,xz)  \,dx$ (unless my logic is incorrect).

Then because X,Y are independent,

= $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x|f_{X}(x)f_Y(xz)  \,dx$.

Would I just then insert the c.d.f for the exponential distribution of X, Y?

Thanks

Comment: In such problems, it is best to start with drawing a diagram of the first quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane (in which the point $(X,Y)$ must lie, and ask for a specific positive _number_ $\alpha$ (take $\alpha = 0.70864$ if you have difficulty thinking abstractly) and ask: Where must the point $(X,Y)$ lie if it is required that $X/Y \leq \alpha$? This is a triangular portion of the first quadrant, and if you integrate the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ over this region, you will have found $P\{X/Y \leq \alpha\} = F_{Z}(\alpha)$. Repeat for other values of $\alpha$ until you see a pattern in the results.

Comment: @user70864 you are on the right path. The integration is for a positive random variables, so adjust you integration limits accordingly.

Comment: @jay-sun The OP seems to have a formula for computing the pdf of $Z$. Simply replacing $f_X(x)$ by $F_X(x)$ and $f_Y(xz)$ by $F_Y(xz)$ in the formula, as he seems to be proposing to do, will not give him the CDF of $Z$.

Comment: Prof @DilipSarwate: I agree with you. I assumed the OP meant PDF instead and should be straightforward to compute CDF from the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

> Would I just then insert the c.d.f for the exponential distribution of X, Y?

Assuming you mistyped c.d.f. for PDF, the answer is "yes".

Note that the computations can be made easier if one notes from the start that $X\gt0$ and $Y\gt0$ almost surely, hence $Z\gt0$ almost surely, and that $Z=X/Y$ yields $X=ZY$. Thus, the approach you explain, while quite sound in principle, rather leads to the fact that, for every $z\geqslant0$,
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty yf_X(yz)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy.
$$
The next step, as you said, is to plug in $f_X(x)=\alpha\mathrm e^{-\alpha x}$ and  $f_Y(y)=\beta\mathrm e^{-\beta y}$ into this, getting
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty \alpha\beta y\exp(-(\alpha z+\beta)y)\mathrm dy.
$$
The change of variable $t=(\alpha z+\beta)y$ yields
$$
f_Z(z)=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha z+\beta)^2}\int_0^\infty t\mathrm e^{-t}\mathrm dt=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha z+\beta)^2}.
$$
If one is interested in the CDF $F_Z$ rather than in the PDF $f_Z$, one simply writes, for every $z\geqslant0$,
$$
F_Z(z)=\int_0^zf_Z(t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^z\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha t+\beta)^2}\mathrm dt,
$$
that is,
$$
F_Z(z)=\left.\frac{-\beta}{\alpha t+\beta}\right|_{t=0}^{t=z}=1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha z+\beta}=\frac{\alpha z}{\alpha z+\beta}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution derived using the mathStatica package for *Mathematica*:

By independence, the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is:

[image]

You seek the cdf of Z, namely $P(Z \le z)$   =   $P(\frac XY \le z)$:

[image]

All done.

Comment: If the **rates** of X and Y are alpha and beta then their densities are **not** the ones you wrote.

Comment: Thanks @Did ... I've changed the Exponential parameterisation from the statistical distribution theory 1/$\alpha$ version to the $\alpha$ rate version, to match OP.